# dropdown menu doesn't show up in navigation bar (a div)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I added a dropdown menu to my website but am unable to get it into my navigation bar.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dLyWs/

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #99CCFF;
}

/* website layout */

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
}

.main-wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 1000px; /* Container width + 2 x 20px */
    border-spacing: 20px 0;
    margin-left: -20px; /* to adjust centering because of increased width (needed for border spacing) */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 652px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
}

.main2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 288px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
}

footer {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/* dropdown menu css */

#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}

#nav li ul{
    margin: 0; 
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0;
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#222;
}

/* links make-up */

a:link {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color:black;
}

a:hover {
    color: #229944;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color:red;
}

#externallink {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* other */

img {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I assume it generates a conflict because my submenu would go over the edge of the navigation bar? How can I fix this?

Cheers!

ps: It's not that I really "need" this navigation bar, I could do without, but I'm just curious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are floating the menu and pushing your navigation menu outside the bar. I'd recommend removing `float:left` and replacing the floats on your `li`'s with `display:inline-block;`:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#nav {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLyWs/1/)

Comment: Hi avalera, thanks for reacting. Wouldn't you say Satwik's solution is easier by simply adjusting the height? Or does it have disadvantages compared to your solution?

Comment: Hi @user3668436, it allows your navigation bar to properly contain its children. By removing the floats, you no longer need to set a height for `.navigation`. If you added another element into Satwik's solution, you would need to set a new height. [His](http://jsfiddle.net/L38cx/2/) vs [Mine](http://jsfiddle.net/dLyWs/2/)

Comment: Hi @avalera, thanks again. I'll mark your answer.

Do you know why I can vertically center my navigation with this padding in my code:

    .navigation {
 margin: 20px 0px;
 padding: 5px 0px;
 background-color: #efefef;
 height: 70px;
    }

I'd think that is a whole lot more than 5px when centered? Yet it works...

Comment: Thanks! Your browser adds its own styles to the `ul` element. In Chrome, it adds `-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` and `-webkit-margin-after: 1em;`. Any extra padding will apply from that position.

Answer (score 0):

Modify you CSS classes as follows:

```
.navigation {
    margin:20px 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid;
    height:70px;
}


#nav {
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

This puts your menu inside the div called navigation.

See this here -> http://jsfiddle.net/L38cx/1/

Hope this helps!!!